# How to center cards in a flex container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, center, flexbox

I want to position these cards exactly in the middle of the lightblue background. And also when I shrink the browser the space between the cards should decrease as well. (I'm using Chrome.)

[image: screenshot]

My style.css file which is not working

```
.flex-item{
    height: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px #aaa;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    webkit-justify-content: center;
    height:380px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    }
```

HTML:

```
       <!-- cards -->
   <div class="flex-container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 flex-item" >
             <img src="bg.jpg" class="img img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:10px; border-radius:250px;">
             <legend>Section</legend> 
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet glo dlbogn</p>
             <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="float:right;" >Read More</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 flex-item" >
             <img src="bg.jpg" class="img img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:10px; border-radius:250px;">
             <legend>Section</legend>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet glo dlbogn</p>
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="float:right;" >Read More</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 flex-item" >
             <img src="bg.jpg" class="img img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:10px; border-radius:250px;">
             <legend>Section</legend>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet glo dlbogn</p>
             <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="float:right;" >Read More</button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `.flex-container` to same element as `.row`.

Since your `.flex-item` is `inline-block` than apply.

```
.flex-container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

For space around your cards - use percentage for it:

```
.flex-item + .flex-item {
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

Remove bootstrap float for `col-` classes:

```
.flex-item {
    float: none;
}
```

It will add margin for all `.flex-item` except first one.

**Example:**

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 150, .3);
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 0, .3);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
}
.flex-item + .flex-item {
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working.. thanks :) but can u explain, how does the text-align property affecting the  cards ? it should affect only the text as far as i know. im novice.

Comment: @MD.TAWSIF-UL-KARIMTawsif It effecting also inline elements. That's why it will effect `display: inline-block` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example working fine

```css
.flex-container {
  background-color: lightblue;
   height:380px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px #aaa;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make some corrections to your current code.

```
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   height: 380px;
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```